# bypass tumblr privacy message in api calls (old api)

Tags: php, tumblr

I have a script to browse through tumblr blogs without looking at all the blogs individually. I use the old, simple tumblr-api. It worked perfect until tumblr now shows one of these new privacy messages first, that one has to click to continue.

I guess, after the click tumblr sets a cookie, but I can't find a way to get this cookie working for my php script...

if you put in the browser:

```
http://nakedworldofmars.tumblr.com/api/read/json?start=0&num=5&type=photo
```

usually you get a json with lot's of data that then can be used. But now this privacy warning comes first. After you once clicked "ok" the api-call works in the browser, actually after the "ok" you are directly redirected and he json-code is delivered. With the next call the warning page does not appear anymore (unless you delete cookies).

Now I use this in a php-script:

```
<?php
$testread = file_get_contents('http://nakedworldofmars.tumblr.com/api/read/json?start=0&num=5&type=photo');
        if (strpos($testread, 'Before you continue') !== false) {
            echo $testread;
}
```

?>

I thought, clicking the "ok" on the echoed page would produce the cookie.

But it doesn't work.

Anybody has any idea how I can make that tumblr knows that my php-script has seen and accepted the page?

Comment: Straight away that URL worked without any privacy diag.. And I never use Tumblr.. Out of interest, why are you not using the new API ?

Comment: @Pogrindis For me that URL only works in browser profiles where I have logged in to tumblr once recently. It does not work from the PHP script; I get the privacy-page (this is only since yesterday).
The new API works with authO and such things that go beyond my scripting horizon (and even if I understood it, I'd have to write my whole script new, that deals with a database of already reblogged posts and much more..)

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem since yesterday – I am using javascript, though. After several trials to solve this using the old API I failed and thus finally just switched to the new API (v2). I also hesitated to do so at first because I am not too familiar with dealing with OAuth keys as well. But it turned out to be quite easy – and it worked instantly. I used this guide as a starting point:
http://www.developerdrive.com/2014/05/how-to-get-started-with-the-tumblr-api-part-1/
http://www.developerdrive.com/2014/05/how-to-get-started-with-the-tumblr-api-part-2/

Comment: thanks for the hints. At least I am not alone :-) I also finally switched to api v2 and rewrote my old script. It works.